# Debian network is constantly restarting

Tags: networking, debian, remote, modprobe

My eth1 network interface is constantly restarting. Googling for this suggests, that [this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=62789) is similar to my problem.
The solution presented there is to either restart the server or rmmod and modprobe the r8169 driver. Or install a newer kernel version, wich would require to restart the server as well. I am currently running 2.6.32-5-686.

My problem is that this is a remote machine to which I currently do not have any physical access. The root harddrive is encrypted with LUKS and as far as I remember I will have to enter the LUKS password at startup befor I can get remote access again. I am not sure here as the machine is used as a server and has been up for a year or so.

kern.log:

```
Oct 15 17:16:02 myMachine kernel: [30591427.202495] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link down
Oct 15 17:16:04 myMachine kernel: [30591428.879283] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link up
Oct 15 17:16:04 myMachine kernel: [30591429.201723] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link down
Oct 15 17:16:06 myMachine kernel: [30591430.787878] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link up
Oct 15 17:19:31 myMachine kernel: [30591636.017630] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link down
Oct 15 17:19:33 myMachine kernel: [30591637.655754] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link up
Oct 15 17:20:38 myMachine kernel: [30591702.701311] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link down
Oct 15 17:20:40 myMachine kernel: [30591704.391792] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link up
Oct 15 17:21:18 myMachine kernel: [30591742.604183] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link down
Oct 15 17:21:19 myMachine kernel: [30591744.267207] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link up
Oct 15 17:24:17 myMachine kernel: [30591921.506034] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link down
Oct 15 17:24:18 myMachine kernel: [30591923.180357] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth1: link up
```

I am thinking of doing

```
rmmod r8169; sleep 30; modprobe r8169
```

but I don't know if this will reasonably sure restart the network driver and my network or if there is something else that need to be done to make sure the network will come back up after the `rmmod`.

Answer (score 1):

your code just restart driver, but I think network will be unusable after that restarting.

you should also add something like `invoke-rc.d networking restart` after it

Comment: Thank you. I will try that, but the constant restarting has gone away for now (I have no idea why) and I will try that the next time I have physical access to the server.

Comment: don't forget, that it can be hardware, not software problem (bad cable, dead switch/network card, etc)